# How to setup secure websockets with nginx

Tags: nginx, https, websocket

I have a webserver running on port 9000 I want to make it available on port 80, and also I want to make a websocket connection available on port 9021. If i run this over `http` everything works fine. But when I go to `https` the websocket cannot be connected.

Here's my nginx config: this gives the warning:

`nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "oyun.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored`

```
server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name          oyun.net;
     ssl_certificate      /etc/key.pem
     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/key2.pem
     listen 80;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:9000
     }
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name          oyun.net;
     ssl_certificate      /etc/key.pem
     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/key2.pem
     listen 9021;
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
 }
```

Here's the browser error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://oyun.net:9021/socket/v1?sri=tcylqwzjnl' failed: 

Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new certification for socket.oyun.net and this config helped

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name oyun.net;
        return 301 https://oyun.net$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name oyun.net;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/oyun.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/oyun.net/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

}
server {
        listen 9021 ssl;
        server_name socket.oyun.net;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.oyun.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.oyun.net/privkey.pem;


        location / {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        }

}
```